# Building ImageMagick with JP2 delegate on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, imagemagick, jpeg2000

I'm trying to install (build) ImageMagick (currently 6.9.0) on a Mac running OS X 10.9.5. 
I need the JP2 support, and for some reasons, while enabling jp2 with configure, I got this warning:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-jp2
```

and the delegates table leave me with a blank as a value:

```
JPEG-2000         --with-jp2=yes
```

and got that at the end:

```
CXXFLAGS        = -g -O2 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
FEATURES        = DPC HDRI OpenMP
DELEGATES       = bzlib mpeg fftw fontconfig freetype jng jpeg pango png ps tiff x zlib
```

I can build it like this but the JP2 won't work, I know it as I tried. 
So I'm kinda stuck here, how can I force the jp2 delegate?

Thanks

Comment: Try `--with-openjp2`

Comment: Adding --with-openjp2 does not work; I got "no" in delegate configuration list and no Jp2 reference appears in the delegate list at the very end. Thanks though.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using homebrew then simply set the appropriate flag, in this case `--with-openjpeg`, so to install you simple do

```
brew install imagemagick --with-openjpeg
```

If imagemagick is already installed then use `brew reinstall imagemagick --with-openjpeg` or uninstall first. Also remember that you can always check the available brew options using `brew info imagemagick` (this holds for any package/formula).

Answer (score 0):

Use brew uninstall ImageMagick. Make sure convert doesn't show anything and then brew install ImageMagick. Hope this helps! Worked for me!